# Django PasswordResetDoneView Not Finding View or URL Pattern

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have been building a user account functionality for a Django app. In doing so, I have come across a problem and am uncertain of whether I am doing something wrong or have encountered an unfamiliar quirk of Django/Python. Any help is appreciated.

I have the following set of (working) urls (**user_accounts/urls.py**):

```
app_name = 'user_accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', views.UserSignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('logout', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/login.html'), name='login'),

    re_path(r'^reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset.html', email_template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_email.html', subject_template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_subject.txt'), name='password_reset'),

    re_path(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

    re_path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    re_path(r'^reset/complete/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

I have been trying to test it as follows (**user_accounts/tests/test_views_forms.py**):

```
class SuccessfulPasswordResetTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        email = 'jon@doe.com'
        User.objects.create_user(username='john', email=email, password='123abcdef')
        url = reverse('user_accounts:password_reset')
        print(reverse('user_accounts:password_reset_done'))
        self.response = self.client.post(url, {'email': email})

    def test_redirection(self):
        '''
        A valid form submission should redirect to password_reset_done
        '''
        url = reverse('password_reset_done')
        self.assertRedirects(self.response, url)
```

The issue is that I get the following error:

> File
>   "/home/user-name/sites/project-web/project/user_accounts/tests/test_views_forms.py",
>   line 128, in setUp
>       self.response = self.client.post(url, {'email': email})
>
> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for
>   'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid
>   view function or pattern name.

Yet, when I navigate directly to `/user/reset/done/` in the browser, it serves the proper template.

The project's `urls.py` file looks as follows. Please note that I am using DjangoCMS

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('video/', include('video_uploader.urls')),
    path('user/', include('user_accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('cms.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the `success_url` attribute in the `PasswordResetView`. Out of the box it [defaults to `reverse_lazy('password_reset_done')`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/efc3e32d6d7fb9bb41be73b80c8607b653c1fbd6/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L208) but since you're using a custom app name the url can't be resolved even though the namespace is the same.

This should do the trick:

```
re_path(r'^reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='user_accounts/password_reset.html',
    success_url=reverse_lazy('user_accounts:password_reset_done'),
    email_template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_email.html',
    subject_template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_subject.txt'), name='password_reset')
```

Comment: Yes, the crux of the issue is correct. I'll award you the bounty and post my working code as a separate answer in case it helps someone. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working code. Note the addition of `success_url` in several paths, which end up working as a cascade. That is one gets triggered after another. I also converted from the regex format to the path format. This may have been needed to get the thing working as well.

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, reverse_lazy, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'user_accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.UserSignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/login.html'), name='login'),

    path('password-change/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset.html', email_template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_email.html', subject_template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_subject.txt',  success_url = reverse_lazy('user_accounts:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),

    path('password-change/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

    #re_path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('password-change/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_confirm.html', success_url = reverse_lazy('user_accounts:password_reset_complete')), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('password-change/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='user_accounts/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete')
]
```